# Traduire « NSFW »

Tags: traduction, anglais

Éternel pourvoyeur de néologismes casse-tête à traduire, Internet a rendu l'usage de "NSFW" (*Not safe for work*) absolument standard, y compris dans des communications quasi-formelles.

Existe-t-il un terme équivalent par le sens *et* la concision (un acronyme ou une locution suffisamment courte pour être utilisable de la même manière) en langue française?

*(je ne cherche pas une traduction littérale, bien entendu)*

Comment: Le pite étant l'usage oral ! Imprononçable tel quel, trop long en entier, on en est réduit à un *enne-esse-effe-double-vé* atroce... pauvres de nous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Je crois que l'acronyme NSFW se répandra en français bien avant qu'on lui trouve un substitut. Je l'ai déjà lu utilisé tel quel sur des pages francophones, et on le trouve dans le [wiktionnaire](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_safe_for_work).

Si je devais en proposer un moi-même, j'inventerais YCSA, pour *Yeux Chastes S'Abstenir*. Je ne me fais pas d'illusions, NSFW l'emportera.

Comment: +1 pour YCSA... Peut-être devrait on en faire une abréviation officielle de FLU ;-) (sans illusion sur son adoption à plus grande échelle)

Answer (score 7):

J'ai vu utiliser et j'utilise moi-même l'expression "Pas au boulot" de manière courante. Cela à l'avantage d'être immédiatement compréhensible par tout francophone.

Je ne pense pas que l'expression "NSFW" soit si répandue et encore moins comprise dans le monde francophone. Personnellement d'ailleurs je ne la connaissais pas.

Answer (score 4):

En France, il n'y a pas de terme équivalent. On peut bien sûr trouver une expression qui ait le même sens, mais elle ne serait pas d'usage courant et avec les même nuances. « NSFW » désigne un contenu qui a en général un caractère sexuel ou un texte contenant des gros mots ; l'expression vient du fait que le simple accès à un contenu de ce genre au travail peut être un motif de sanction. Or la sociologie française est très différente sur ce point, il n'y a pas de type de contenu comparable. S'il y avait un type de contenu « à éviter au travail » en France, ce serait plutôt de la politique. Quant au type de contenu couvert par NSFW, il correspond à ce que l'on appellerait quelquefois *risqué*.

Comment: Aussi ouvert et "décontracté" (certains diront "sexiste") que soit l'environnement professionnel typique français, je doute qu'il soit de bon ton d'ouvrir une page présentant des demoiselles dévêtues (ou plus) devant son chef de bureau... ;-)

Comment: @Dave Non, en France, je pense qu'il vaut déjà mieux ouvrir un site porno que celui de la CGT. Quant à l'autre partie de NSFW, les gros mots, ça personne ne fera attention tant que ce n'est pas devant un client.

Comment: non c'est faux. Aucun chef ou collègue ne t'en voudra si sur un de tes onglets du navigateur il y a le site de la CGT. Ca pourrait être pour des raisons juste informatives. Par contre je pense que leur tête sera bien différente s'ils te trouvent devant un site porno ou gore.

Comment: En france je doute que le 'risqué' mène à une sanction directe, plutôt une réaction à chaud des collègues que cela dérange. Evidemment cela dépend aussi du milieu, je me rappelle d'un chef d'atelier qui décorait son bureau avec des calendriers PlayBoy et des images extraites de magazines similaires, je ne croit pas que cela lui aie jamais valu plus que des remarques vaguement paternelles de la part des supérieurs ("ce calendrier est de l'année dernière, il faudra peut-être ranger ta piaule") et quelques sobriquets. Il était aussi représentant du syndicat, même punition (même motif?)...

Answer (score 3):

Je traduirais par **RPLT**: Risqué Pour Le Travail

Comment: Pourquoi pas plutôt RAT: Risqué Au Travail ? Ce n'est pas tellement "pour" le travail que c'est risqué.

Answer (score 1):

On voit parfois "contenu explicite". Mais "contenu explicite" a un sens un peu plus large que NSFW.